# Visual Studio Code: \n in regex file search not supported?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm trying a simple regex search with "\n" to find a line feed and some String(s) around. In a single file search it´s working fine (see screenshot on the right), but in a folder search I get the error "Literal '\n' not allowed" (see screen shot on the left). Any idea?

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wimhr.png)

Cheers Daniel

Comment: There was just a question on this so this is a duplicate - use  '\\n'.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I believe this error is coming from [ripgrep](https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep), which VSCode uses by default for this search function.  I found [this comment](https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep/issues/196#issuecomment-362312998) by the owner, referencing `\n` in particular.

Fortunately, you can tell VSCode not to use ripgrep in your `settings.json`:

```
"search.useRipgrep": false
```

With ripgrep disabled, `\n` should work as expected.

Comment: That comment has nothing to do with this question. `\n` isn't allowed in the regex because the current release of ripgrep doesn't support matching across multiple lines.